# How to program custom buttons to navigate through scroll view created with Scroll Rect combined with a Mask

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui

I have a shop GUI, its content in a srollview created with Scroll Rect and Mask combination and can be scrolled down and up.

Right now, the scroll view scrolls by clicking and dragging with the mouse anywhere in scroll view area, or by interacting with a vertical scrollbar.

How do I use custom up and down buttons (circled in red on attached image below) to make the scroll happen?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Copy the following script to your project and apply ScrollRectSnap script to your scroll view . Know if you have done this to make your scroll view snap on button click simply do the following link **UpArrowPressed** and **DownArrowPressed** with your up and down buttons and do not forget to check **Snap In V** parameter in inspector of **ScrollRectSnap** if you have vertical scrollview and also do not get confused by snapper.DraggedOnRight() call in your DownArrowPressed function as if you have checked **Snap In V** parameter it will then act like snap down and similler thing with snapper.DraggedOnLeft() other parameters you can set according to your requirment you will have to play with values in order to get it according to your requirments.

```
public void UpArrowPressed()
{
    ScrollRectSnap snapper = GetComponentInChildren<ScrollRectSnap>();
    snapper.DraggedOnLeft();
}

public void DownArrowPressed()
{
    ScrollRectSnap snapper = GetComponentInChildren<ScrollRectSnap>();
    snapper.DraggedOnRight();

}
```

```js
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class ScrollRectSnap : MonoBehaviour 
{
 
 float[] points;
 [Tooltip("how many screens or pages are there within the content (steps)")]
 public int screens = 1;
 [Tooltip("How quickly the GUI snaps to each panel")]
 public float snapSpeed;
 public float inertiaCutoffMagnitude;
 float stepSize;
 
 ScrollRect scroll;
 bool LerpH;
 float targetH;
 [Tooltip("Snap horizontally")]
 public bool snapInH = true;
 
 bool LerpV;
 float targetV;
 [Tooltip("Snap vertically")]
 public bool snapInV = true;

 public string controllTag;
 bool dragInit = true;
 int dragStartNearest;
 float horizontalNormalizedPosition;
 float verticalNormalizedPosition;

 public static event Action<int,int> OnEndReached;
 public static event Action<int,int,string> OnEndReachedWithTag;

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start()
 {
  Init();
//  SnapToSelectedIndex(0);
 }

 void Init()
 {
  scroll = gameObject.GetComponent<ScrollRect>();
  scroll.inertia = true;
  
  if (screens > 0)
  {
   points = new float[screens];
   stepSize = (float)Math.Round(1 / (float)(screens - 1),2);
   
   for (int i = 0; i < screens; i++)
   {
    points[i] = i * stepSize;
   }
  }
  else
  {
   points[0] = 0;
  }
 }

 void OnEnable()
 {

 }

 void Update()
 {
  horizontalNormalizedPosition = scroll.horizontalNormalizedPosition;
  verticalNormalizedPosition = scroll.verticalNormalizedPosition;

  if (LerpH)
  {
   scroll.horizontalNormalizedPosition = Mathf.Lerp(scroll.horizontalNormalizedPosition, targetH, snapSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
   if (Mathf.Approximately((float)Math.Round(scroll.horizontalNormalizedPosition,2), targetH)) 
   {
    LerpH = false;
    int target = FindNearest(scroll.horizontalNormalizedPosition, points);
//    Debug.LogError("Target : " + target);
    if (target == points.Length-1) 
    {
     if (OnEndReached != null)  
     {
      OnEndReached(1,target); 
     }
     if(OnEndReachedWithTag != null)
     {
      OnEndReachedWithTag(1,target,controllTag);
     }
    }
    else if (target == 0)  
    {
     if (OnEndReached != null)  
     {
      OnEndReached(-1,target); 
     }
     if(OnEndReachedWithTag != null)
     {
      OnEndReachedWithTag(-1,target,controllTag);
     }
    }
    else
    {
     if (OnEndReached != null)  
     {
      OnEndReached(0,target); 
     }
     if(OnEndReachedWithTag != null)
     {
      OnEndReachedWithTag(0,target,controllTag);
     }
    }
   
   }
  }
  if (LerpV)
  {
   scroll.verticalNormalizedPosition = Mathf.Lerp(scroll.verticalNormalizedPosition, targetV, snapSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
   if (Mathf.Approximately(scroll.verticalNormalizedPosition, targetV)) 
   {
    LerpV = false;
   }
  }
 }
 
 public void DragEnd()
 {
  int target = FindNearest(scroll.horizontalNormalizedPosition, points);
  
  if (target == dragStartNearest && scroll.velocity.sqrMagnitude > inertiaCutoffMagnitude * inertiaCutoffMagnitude)
  {
   if (scroll.velocity.x < 0)
   {
    target = dragStartNearest + 1;
   }
   else if (scroll.velocity.x > 1)
   {
    target = dragStartNearest - 1;
   }
   target = Mathf.Clamp(target, 0, points.Length - 1);
  }
  
  if (scroll.horizontal && snapInH )
  {
   targetH = points[target];
   LerpH = true;
  }
  if (scroll.vertical && snapInV && scroll.verticalNormalizedPosition > 0f && scroll.verticalNormalizedPosition < 1f)
  {
   targetH = points[target];
   LerpH = true;
  }
  
  dragInit = true;
 }
 
 public void OnDrag()
 {
  if (dragInit)
  {
   if (scroll == null)  
   {
    scroll = gameObject.GetComponent<ScrollRect>(); 
   }
   dragStartNearest = FindNearest(scroll.horizontalNormalizedPosition, points);
   dragInit = false;
  }
  
  LerpH = false;
  LerpV = false;
 }
 
 int FindNearest(float f, float[] array)
 {
  float distance = Mathf.Infinity;
  int output = 0;
  for (int index = 0; index < array.Length; index++)
  {
   if (Mathf.Abs(array[index] - f) < distance)
   {
    distance = Mathf.Abs(array[index] - f);
    output = index;
   }
  }
  return output;
 }

 public void DraggedOnLeft()
 {
  OnDrag();

  if (scroll.horizontal && snapInH && scroll.horizontalNormalizedPosition > -0.001f && scroll.horizontalNormalizedPosition < 1.001f)
  {
//   Debug.Log("Before Press, LerpH : " + LerpH);
   if (dragStartNearest < points.Length-1)  
   {
    targetH = points[dragStartNearest+1];
    LerpH = true;
   }
   else
   {
    targetH = points[dragStartNearest];
    LerpH = true;
   }
//   Debug.Log("After Press, LerpH : " + LerpH);
  }
  if (scroll.vertical && snapInV && scroll.verticalNormalizedPosition > 0f && scroll.verticalNormalizedPosition < 1f)
  {

   if (dragStartNearest < points.Length-1)  
   {
    targetV = points[dragStartNearest+1];
    LerpV = true;
   }
   else
   {
    targetV = points[dragStartNearest];
    LerpV = true;
   }
  }
  
  dragInit = true;
 }
 public void DraggedOnRight()
 {
  OnDrag();
  
  if (scroll.horizontal && snapInH && scroll.horizontalNormalizedPosition > -0.001f && scroll.horizontalNormalizedPosition < 1.001f)
  {
   if (dragStartNearest>0)  
   {
    targetH = points[dragStartNearest-1];
    LerpH = true;
   }
   else
   {
    targetH = points[dragStartNearest];
    LerpH = true;
   }
  }
  if (scroll.vertical && snapInV && scroll.verticalNormalizedPosition > 0f && scroll.verticalNormalizedPosition < 1f)
  {
   if (dragStartNearest > 0) 
   {
    targetV = points[dragStartNearest-1];
    LerpV = true;    
   }
   else
   {
    targetV = points[dragStartNearest];
    LerpV = true;    
   }
  }
  
  dragInit = true;
 }

 public void SnapToSelectedIndex(int index)
 {
  if (points == null)  
  {
   Init();   
  }
  dragInit = false;
  LerpH = false;
  LerpV = false;
  targetH = points[index];
  LerpH = true;
  dragInit = true;
 }

}
```